# Objects not being created, just began learning rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i am trying to code a controller that saves an object from a form. I defined a create method that I think should be correct.

```
def create
@info = Info.new(params[:info])

if @info != nil
    @display_message = 'Object created successfully, thank you'
else
    @display_message = 'Sorry! Object was not created successfully'
    render 'index'
    end
 end
```

However when I submit the form and call Info.all in the rails console, I only get and empty array.

```
<h1>Please enter information about an Info object</h1>
<%= form_for @info, :action => :create do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_field :title %> <br />
<%= f.label :price %><br />
<%= f.text_field :price %> <br />
<%= f.submit "Submit" %> <br />
<% end %>
```

As far as I know this should work, localhost:3000 isnt throwing any errors with syntax and displays the form fine. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your object to persistance. So your controller method should look like code below

```
def create
  @info = Info.new(params[:info])

  if @info.save
    flash[:success] = 'Object created successfully, thank you'
    render :index
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Sorry! Object was not created successfully'
    render :new
  end
end
```

Also use rails `flash` object to show messages to user.

Comment: how then do i display the message in the view? Im just starting with rails and am unfamiliar with flash[]

Comment: Just use flash object in your views.
`<%= flash[:success] %>` for example

Answer (score 1):

You're only instantiating it, not saving it, e.g.,

```
@info.save
```

Although you might want to consider the render, since a refresh might not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Info.new` only initializes an object it does not persist it. Either call `Info.create` or `@info.save`.

You don't need the `nil` check either since the object is being initialized is always returned.